# If a blank Azure Subscription is provided, how do you deploy a new Resource Group, and is it free?

Tags: azure

If a blank Azure Subscription is provided, how do you deploy a new Resource Group, and is it free?

And following deployment of a new Resource Group, are there any steps that need to be undertaken before deploying resources to the newly created resource group?

Comment: Not sure I follow. A resource group is "just" a way to group resources. It does not cost anything by itself. The resource deployed to the group may have costs attached. And no, there are no special steps needed to deploy a resources to a resource group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do you deploy a new Resource Group, and is it free?

There are various API's (REST API, Powershell, Azure CLI) to do this. The easiest is doing it interactively from the Azure portal. A resource group is free

> And following deployment of a new Resource Group, are there any steps that need to be undertaken before deploying resources to the newly created resource group?

Generally No. Unless it is locked (by default it isn't) or has specific security stopping you (which won't be an isse if you are the same user)